# attr_accessor needed for unit tests, but prevents the fields from being written to otherwise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing

before I started writing tests to flesh out what some methods should do, my model only had the belong / has clauses at the top of the file. All was well.

But when I started writing tests, I kept getting 'attribute=' not defined errors.

So i'm  like, well that's weird, I thought getters and setters were implemented by default. Apparently they aren't for unit testing. so I added `attr_accessor :selected_end_index, :selected_start_index, :revision_number` one at a time, as I hoped that it was just a problem with one attribute. nope, it was with all of them.

I get all my tests passing, and then I go back to coding, when all of the sudden, I can't write to these attributes anymore.

I create the model by doing Change.new(:revision_number => 3, etc) but these fields are all null in the datebase.

When I removed the `attr_accessor :selected_end_index, :selected_start_index, :revision_number` line from my model, everything started working again (aside from the tests, of course)

What is going on here? How do I get these attributes to be accessible to my unit tests and in dev environment.

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7, and Rails 2.3.8.
Also using the default unit test framework (along with Factory Girl)

Update: adding code
This works without the attr_accessor but not when I have the attr_accessor:

```
change = Change.new(:kind => Change::CHANGE,
                    :status => Change::NEW,
                    :revision_number => latest_revision,
                    :content_id => params[:content_id],
                    :selected_text => selected_text,
                    :selected_start_index => selection_index_within_content_body,
                    :selected_end_index => selection_end_index_within_content_body,
                    :selection_hash => hash,
                    :suggested_text => params[:suggested_text],
                    :name_of_user => cookies[:login_name])
```

When the above is saved to the DB, the selected_start/end_index and revision is saved without a problem when I don't have the attr_accessor.

```
@a = Factory(:change, :content_id => content[:id], 
                    :selected_start_index => 10,
                    :selected_end_index => 12)
```

The above (from my unit test) does not work without the attr_accessor. it says selected_start_index= is an undefined method. but when I add the attr_accessor line. the test continues and eventually succeeds.

Comment: Can you show an example of a class you had, and the code that used the class?

Comment: ActiveRecord implements getters and setters for DB fields only. Did you perchance not create/migrate the DB? Also...Test::Unit is unnecessarily painful. I recommend RSpec instead.

Comment: I'll add some code in a bit. Yeah everything is migrated, as I said: controller / model code works when I don't have the attr_accessor line. and doesn't in testing.

Comment: But have you migrated your *test database*?  ActiveRecord depends on the ability to reflect on what is in your database.

Comment: oh dear. I probably haven't. and that would explain everything. T_T

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser If I already have 6k lines of tests, is it worth the switch?

Comment: IMHO yes, particularly if you do it gradually. We did that at a previous job of mine.

Comment: What would you say is the best page / resource for rspec?

Comment: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec or (so I've heard) The RSpec Book.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the classes you want to test inside your test.

Example:

```
class A
  def initialize(value)
    @a = value
  end
  def double
    @a = @a * 2
  end
end
```

When you want to test the internal values you need the reader. You can extend A inside your test:

```
require 'test/unit'

class A
  attr_reader :a
end

class Test_A < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_1
    a = A.new(1)
    assert_equal( 1, a.a )
    a.double
    assert_equal( 2, a.a )
  end
end
```